# Wordpress JSON showing only latest 20 posts of my Wordpress Blog

Tags: json, wordpress, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I want to create a Windows Phone application of my wordpress website. For this I am retrieving the JSON from the url - http://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites//posts.
My problem is that the JSON on this URL contains only 20 posts. How do I retrieve all the posts?
I am using WinRT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the documentation here https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/get/sites/%24site/posts/

set the query variable `number`, to the amount of posts you desire, max 100